# What are the changes being made to the NSW ICAC (Independent commission against corruption)

Tags: government, australia, corruption

There are some apparently controversial changes being made to ICAC(https://www.icac.nsw.gov.au/) in New South Wales there is more comment about the motivations than the substance what are the changes being made

http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-11-15/sweeping-changes-to-icac-might-see-megan-latham-lose-job/8027442

Answer (score 1):

Under current arrangements, there is a single fulltime ICAC Commissioner who makes the sole decision as to what matters should be subject to public enquiry.

In the new arrangements, there will continue to be a single fulltime commissioner, but that commissioner will need to get agreement from two other part time commissioners before commencing any enquiry.

ICAC will also need to give any person subject to an adverse finding from an enquiry the opportunity to respond to those findings before publication.