# Will the changes to the NSW ICAC reduce its effectiveness?

Tags: government, australia, corruption

The NSW government is putting through changes to ICAC, they claim its to make it more effective but it can also look like its because ICAC has been too effective at finding problems with the party.

News Article
http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-11-16/former-minister-slams-icac-as-government-passes-overhaul/8031498

Related Question: [What are the changes being made to the NSW ICAC (Independent commission against corruption)](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13647/what-are-the-changes-being-made-to-the-nsw-icac-independent-commission-against)